# Combine two dataframes in Pandas to generate many to many relationship

Tags: pandas, dataframe, random, many-to-many, associations

I have two lists, say

```
customers = ['a', 'b', 'c']
accounts = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I want to generate a Pandas dataframe so:

1. All customers and accounts are used
2. There is a many to many relationship between customers and accounts (one customer 'may' have multiple accounts and an account 'may' be owned by multiple customers
3. I want the many to many relationship to be random. That is, some customers will have one account and some will have more than one. Similarly, some accounts will be owned by just one customers and others by more than one.

Something like,

| Customer | Account |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |
| a | 4 |
| b | 4 |
| c | 4 |
| b | 5 |
| b | 6 |
| b | 7 |
| b | 8 |
| a | 9 |

Since I am generating random data, in the worst case scenario, I can generate way too many accounts and discard the unused ones if the code is easier (essentially relaxing the requirement 1 above).

I am using `sample (n=20, replace=True)` to generate 20 records in both dataframes and then merging them into one based on the index. Is there an out of the box API or library to do this or is my code the recommended way?

```
customers = ['a', 'b', 'c']
accounts = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

customers_df = pd.DataFrame(data=customers)
customers_df = customers_df.sample (n=20, replace=True)
customers_df['new_index'] = range (20)
customers_df.set_index ('new_index', inplace=True)
accounts_df = pd.DataFrame (data=accounts)
accounts_df = accounts_df.sample (n=20, replace=True)
accounts_df['new_index'] = range (20)
accounts_df.set_index ('new_index', inplace=True)
combined_df = pd.merge (customers_df, accounts_df, on='new_index')
print (combined_df)
```

Edit: Modified the question and added sample code I have tried.

Comment: _What is the best way to..._ is an opinion based question. SO is not a coding service. Please read the following documentation, then [edit], and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Always provide a [mre] with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)** & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to collect the set of all possible relationships with a cartesian product, then select from that list before building your dataframe:

```
import itertools
import random

customers = ['a', 'b', 'c']
accounts = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
possible_associations = [ca for ca in itertools.product(customers, accounts)]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(random.choices(possible_associations, k=20), columns=['customers', 'accounts']).sort_values(['customers','accounts'])
print(df)
```

#### Output

```
   customers  accounts
0          a         2
3          a         2
15         a         2
18         a         4
16         a         5
14         a         7
7          a         8
12         a         8
1          a         9
2          b         5
9          b         5
8          b         8
11         b         8
19         c         2
17         c         3
5          c         4
4          c         5
6          c         5
13         c         5
10         c         7
```

Comment: I considered that but the cartesian product will match every customer with every account. That's not what I want. I want some customers to have 1 account, some to have more than one account. Similarly, I want some accounts to have one customer and some to have more than one. Basically, I am looking to create a random many to many associations.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I've updated my answer to have random associations. Is this more like what you were trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

To have a repeatable test result, start with `np.random.seed(1)` (in the target
version drop it).

Then proceed as follows:

1. Create a list of probabilities - how many accounts can have a customer, e.g.:

   ```
   prob = [0.5, 0.25, 0.15, 0.09, 0.01]
   ```
2. Generate a *Series* stating how many owners shall have each account:

   ```
   cnt = pd.Series(np.random.choice(range(1, len(prob) + 1), size=len(accounts),
       p=prob), name='Customer')
   ```

   Its name is *Customer*, because it will be the source to create just
   *Customer* column.

   For my sample probablities and generator seeding the result is:

   ```
   0    1
   1    2
   2    1
   3    1
   4    1
   5    1
   6    1
   7    1
   8    1
   Name: Customer, dtype: int32
   ```

   (the left column is the index, the right - actual values).

   Because your data sample contains only *9* accounts, the result does
   not contain "greater" number of owners. But in your target version,
   with more accounts, there will be accounts with greater numbers of
   owners.
3. Generate the result - *cust_acct* DataFrame, defining the assignment of customers
   to accounts:

   ```
   cust_acct = cnt.apply(lambda x: np.random.choice(customers, x, replace=False))\
       .explode().to_frame().join(pd.Series(accounts, name='Account')).reset_index(drop=True)
   ```

The result, for your sample data and my seeding and probabilities, is:

```
  Customer  Account
0        b        1
1        a        2
2        b        2
3        b        3
4        b        4
5        c        5
6        b        6
7        c        7
8        a        8
9        b        9
```

Of course, you can assume different proabilities in *prob*.
You can also choose other "top" number of owners (the number of
entries in *prob*).
In this case no change in code is needed, because the range of values in
the first *np.random.choice* is set to accomodete to the lenght of *prob*.

**Note:** Because your sample data contains **only 3** customers,
under different generator seeding there can occur *ValueError: Cannot
take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'*.

The reason is that if the number of owners for some account was > 3 then just
this error occurs.

But with your target data, with greater number of customers, this error
will not occur.